# Gatsby not rebuilding whenever mounted code changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gatsby

I used the typical gatsby init given by the gatsby-cli. And, I wanted to use docker to automate even further.

```
.
|- src
|- gatsby-*.js
|- node_modules
|- Dockerfile
|- docker-compose.yml
|- package*.json
|- public
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

# Add the package.json file and build the node_modules folder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN mkdir node_modules && npm install
RUN npm install --global gatsby-cli && gatsby telemetry --disable
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gatsby:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    command: gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
     - .:/app
     - /app/node_modules/
```

The problem is that whenever I change anything locally and I have verified this through going inside the container to make sure the changes was copied to the container, the changes didn't trigger a build.

I have no problems with accessing the exposed port in my localhost. Anything that I did wrong? I have verified that the build does run but only once. There's no indication of errors during the build process only WARN stuff from npm installs which was also the case when I installed locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I wasn't using google keywords right. If only I used the word, recompile instead of rebuilding.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10836

This made it work for me.